# How can picture 1 be x KB and picture 2 be x MB?

Tags: macos, images

I have made two screenshots:

[image]
[image]

- Size of 1: 751.039 bytes (754 KB)
- Size of 2: 3.739.946 bytes (3,7 MB)

How is this possible? They're both screenshots, made with the same program (the built-in Mac OS X program), the same program (Google Chrome) is taken a screenshot of, though the difference in size is huge. How is this possible?

(Note: 2 is very low-quality because I couldn't find an image hosting service which allows me to upload up to 3 MB without lowering the quality of the picture.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the dimensions of the picture that matters, but rather the detail(and colours etc):

A picture with more colours and details won't be able to be compressed as much as a simple picture with little detail and few colours and will result in a larger file size. It's all in how the jpg algorithm works. If you have a photo of nothing but a blank white wall, then it can be compressed (and expressed) simply as something like "1 million pixels of white". Or another way of explaining it if you have a typical scene, and there are 5 pixels in a row of an identical colour like in a blue sky, the jpg encoding will simplify that and express it as "5 blue" rather than "blue, blue, blue, blue, blue". It takes less bytes to express "5 blue" than "blue, blue, blue, blue, blue".

That's why if every pixel in the picture was the same colour(in your case 1, **white**) it would compress extremely efficiently whereas a picture with lots of fine detail won't.

> At identical settings, the amount of details in the image determines file size. Images with file detail produce bigger JPEGs than blurry shots.
>
> The amount and shades of color or tones has a significant effect on JPG file size also.

[More info here.](http://photo.net/digital-darkroom-forum/00NVkJ)

Comment: That's very interesting. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Welcome, glad it helped! The same principle can also be applied to file compression too(just replace the pixels with code) :)